# Route [...] not defined even though it exists on Laravel 9.37.0

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-9

So I'm working on an application on Laravel, and I'm running into the issue. A route that I have defined in my web.php is said to not exist :
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXXD1.png)

I have already looked up here about people having a similar problem, but none of the solution I have found worked. I really don't know what to do to be honest so I'm taking any idea you can come up with.

By the way, it is in my route:list
[route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbbVL.png)

This is the code in my view :

```
<a href="{{route('categorie', $service->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-1"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i></a>
```

And there is the code in my web.php :

```
Route::resource('service', ServiceController::class);
Route::resource('categorie', CategorieController::class);
Route::resource('ticket', TicketController::class);
```

I tried to make a new Route::get and add a name('categorie') but i won't work either, and it's not a surprise since Route::resource is supposed to already make named route, but it was worth to try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no route name "categorie", but there is "categorie.index", run php artisan route:list to see all your route names. Route::resource creates a few routes, not just one.

Comment: i've cut a big part of the routes on the screenshot since there is too many. But service is present and isn't a problem, at least for now.

Comment: Nevermind it seems that the reason was that stupid... I've spent 2 hours looking for this, I feel so stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `categorie.show`

```
<a href="{{route('categorie.show', $service->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-1"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i></a>
```

Comment: Yes ! I've tried with index at first but the method don't like using argument so I went with show. Thanks !